# Before intent is changing spinner also change its value

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

After I press the button "ΕΙΣΟΔΟΣ" a new intent is called and the spinner change its value, to first item. Although it does not effect my app, it is disturbing. I cannot find where the issue is...

the code of this activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_login);

        //region find views by their IDs
        spinnerNames = findViewById(R.id.spin);
        startButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_log_in);
        etNameLogIn = findViewById(R.id.et_name_log_in);
        bodyHuman = findViewById(R.id.ll_body_human);
        bodyWiFi = findViewById(R.id.ll_body_wifi);
        imageHuman = findViewById(R.id.rl_image_human);
        imageWiFi = findViewById(R.id.rl_image_wifi);
        //endregion

        checkConnection();

        //region set on item selected listener and set also editText name log in when select from spinner
        spinnerNames.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                firstTime += 1;

                SpinnerItem clickedItem = (SpinnerItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                String clickedName = clickedItem.getName();

                if (firstTime > 1) {
                    etNameLogIn.setText(clickedName);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        //endregion

        etNameLogIn.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);


                    getWindow().getDecorView().clearFocus();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (startButton.getText().equals("ΑΝΑΝΕΩΣΗ")) {
                    checkConnection();
                } else if (startButton.getText().equals("ΕΙΣΟΔΟΣ")) {
                    checkConnection();

                    // region check whether editText log in name exists in spinner if not add it to database and spinner
                    for (int z = 0; z < mspinnerList.size(); z++) {
                        if (etNameLogIn.getText().toString().equals(mspinnerList.get(z).getName())) {
                            yes += 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (yes == 0) {
                        mspinnerList.add(new SpinnerItem(etNameLogIn.getText().toString(), R.drawable.next_48));
                        try {
                            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
                            connect = connectionHelper.connections();
                            if (connect == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Δεν υπάρχει σύνδεση με τη βάση δεδομένων.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {
                                String sqlQuery = myQuery;
                                Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                                stmt.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);

                                isSuccess = true;
                                connect.close();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            isSuccess = false;
                        }
                    }
                    //endregion

                    if (startButton.getText().equals("ΕΙΣΟΔΟΣ")) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("NAME", etNameLogIn.getText().toString()); //Optional parameters
                        MainLoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    }

                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && requestCode == LOCATION){
            //User allowed the location and you can read it now
            checkConnection();
        }
    }

    private void checkConnection() {
        //If requested permission isn't Granted yet
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Request permission from user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
        }else{//Permission already granted
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            if(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED){
                String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();//Here you can access your SSID
                if (ssid.equals("\"private-Pda\"") || ssid.equals("\"AndroidWifi\"") ) {
                    initList();
                    imageHuman.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bodyHuman.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageWiFi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bodyWiFi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    startButton.setText("ΕΙΣΟΔΟΣ");
                } else  {
                    imageWiFi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bodyWiFi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageHuman.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bodyHuman.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    startButton.setText("ΑΝΑΝΕΩΣΗ");
                }

            } else  {
                imageWiFi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bodyWiFi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageHuman.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bodyHuman.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                startButton.setText("ΑΝΑΝΕΩΣΗ");
            }
        }
    }

    private void initList() {
        mspinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
            connect = connectionHelper.connections();
            if (connect == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Δεν υπάρχει σύνδεση με τη βάση δεδομένων.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                String sqlQuery = "SELECT ONOMA FROM [KOMBOS].[dbo].[CCCAPOGRAFI]";
                Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    mspinnerList.add(new SpinnerItem(rs.getString("ONOMA"), R.drawable.next_48));
                }

                mAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, mspinnerList);
                spinnerNames.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                isSuccess = true;
                connect.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Video](https://youtu.be/kQP2buqHnvQ) that represents how my app is behaving. I have searched but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think (but not 100% sure) it may be due to activity live cycle: onStop() method is invoked, which erase local data from your spinner and jumps to begenning of the array linked to AdapterView.

Overload onSaveInstanceState:

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
   outState.putInt("position", [variable with chosen position])
}
```

And add to onCreate:

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
    [variable with chosen position] = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
    // with that variable set position in your spinner here
}
```

Although I don't know if adding in onCreate() will do.

You can also try overloading OnStop() and setting spinner value.
Hope that helps

Comment: OK so what do you propose?